# react-native-fs DocumentDirectoryPath Where is the catalog on the phone？

Tags: android, react-native

https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs

```js
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

console.log(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath);

// /data/data/a.a.a/files

RNFS.writeFile(
  RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.txt',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  'utf8',
)
  .then(success => console.log('FILE WRITTEN!'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
```

But this file is not on the phone `/Android/data/a.a.a/files/test.txt`

Where is this file ?

Answer (score 0):

I used this :-  RNFS.ExternalDirectoryPath + '/test.txt',
It stores the test.txt file in the same location where the "RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath" stores the file.
It worked in my case...i was storing logFile & was facing same issue.